# Inserting into a Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, new-operator, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create a doubly linked list container for a project. I cannot use any std containers. The doubly linked list has to be sorted. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class dll {
private:
    struct Node {
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
        T data;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    dll();
    ~dll();

    void insert(T value);

    bool empty() const { return head == tail; };
};

template <typename T> dll<T>::dll() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = head;
}

template <typename T> dll<T>::~dll() {
    delete[] head;
}

template <typename T> void dll<T>::insert(T value) {
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->data = value;
    // Case 1: There are no nodes yet
    if (head == nullptr) {
        node->prev = nullptr;
        node->next = nullptr;
        head = node;
        tail = head;
    }
    else {
        // Case 2: There is more than one node
        Node *curr = head;
        if (curr->next != nullptr)
        {
            while (curr->next) {
                // If the value is less than the current value
                if (value < curr->data) {
                    Node *temp = new Node;
                    temp->data = curr->data;
                    temp->next = curr->next;
                    temp->prev = curr->prev;
                    node->next = temp;
                    node->prev = temp->prev;
                    curr->prev = node;
                }
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
        // Case 3: There is only one node
        else {
            node->prev = head;
            node->next = nullptr;
            tail = node;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    dll<int> list;
    list.insert(10);
    list.insert(20);
    list.insert(15);
}
```

The problem I am having is in my insert function. I am using the debugger and stepping into the code at the line: list.insert(10);.

It correctly goes into the first case where head == nullptr and creates the Node.
When I step into the next line of code (list.insert(20) ), it creates a node with this line: Node *node = new Node; 
But it is creating the node with the memory address that head is pointing to.

I put a watch on the head variable and the node variable and the memory addresses were the same.Basically it is creating the same Node as it did for the last insertion.

I don't know how to get the line: Node *code = new Node; to create something new. Am I using the new keyword wrong here?

Comment: "dll" is probably not the best name for a doubly-linked-list.  It means something entirely different on Windows. :)

Comment: What is the point of `temp`? Why not use `curr`? And then why set `node->next` to be temp? You're effectively making a hole in your list. Also, you've forgotten to update the node *behind* `node`.

Comment: delete[] head; the usage of delete is wrong

Comment: You could simplify your list by using a sentinel node.

Comment: While there are several things wrong with your code as mentioned already, the problem with creating objects in the same address does not happen to me: http://ideone.com/RX5NyR

Answer (score 1):

To make the initialization of Node easier, let's add a reasonable constructor that initializes prev and next members to null.  That makes things easier for later code.

```
struct Node {
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    T data;
    Node() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr)
    {

    }
};
```

There's always four cases to be aware of in a linked list problem.  Some of which you got.  Inserting into an empty list. Inserting at the front of the list, inserting at the end of the list, and the middle.

```
template <typename T> void dll<T>::insert(T value) {
    Node *node = new Node;
    node->data = value;

    // Case 1: There are no nodes yet
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = node;
        tail = head;
        return;
    }


    // case 2 - inserting at the head of the list
    if (node->data < head->data)
    {
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        return;
    }

    // case 3 - inserting at the end of the list
    if (node->data >= tail->data)
    {
        node->prev = tail;
        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
        return;
    }

    // general case - inserting into the middle
    Node* probe = head;
    while (probe && (node->data >= probe->data))
    {
        probe = probe->next;
    }
    if (probe)
    {
        node->next = probe;
        node->prev = probe->prev;
        probe->prev->next = node;
        probe->prev = node;
        return;
    }

    // error - we shouldnt' reach this point. If we did, it meant the list was out of order to begin with.
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks selbie! That helped a lot.

Comment: Seeing how I'm exactly 5 points short of hitting the 20K milestone, why don't you help **me** out... :)

Comment: @selbie xD here 's 10 from mine for that

Answer (score 0):

First of all the destructor is invalid. This statement

```
delete[] head;
```

means that head is an array. However head is not an array. It is a pointer to a single object of type Node. You have to delete all nodes of the list in the destructor. The destructor can look the following way

```
template <typename T> 
dll<T>::~dll() 
{
    while ( head )
    {
        Node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

As for the method insert then it can look very simply. For example

```
template <typename T> 
void dll<T>::insert( const T &value ) 
{
    Node *current  = head;
    Node *previous = nullptr;

    while ( current && !( value < current->data ) )
    {
        previous = current;
        current  = current->next;
    }

    Node *node = new Node { previous, current, value };

    if ( previous == nullptr ) head = node;
    else previous->next = node;

    if ( current  == nullptr ) tail = node;
    else current->prev = node;
}
```

And there is no any need and reason to add a constructor to structure Node.  It is better when it is an aggregate.

Here is a test program

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class dll 
{
private:
    struct Node 
    {
        Node *prev;
        Node *next;
        T data;
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

public:
    dll();
    ~dll();

    void insert( const T &value);

    bool empty() const { return head == tail; };

    void print() const;
};

template <typename T> 
dll<T>::dll() 
{
    head = tail = nullptr;
}

template <typename T> 
dll<T>::~dll() 
{
    while ( head )
    {
        Node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

template <typename T> 
void dll<T>::insert( const T &value ) 
{
    Node *current  = head;
    Node *previous = nullptr;

    while ( current && !( value < current->data ) )
    {
        previous = current;
        current  = current->next;
    }

    Node *node = new Node { previous, current, value };

    if ( previous == nullptr ) head = node;
    else previous->next = node;

    if ( current  == nullptr ) tail = node;
    else current->prev = node;
}

template <typename T> 
void dll<T>::print() const
{
    for ( Node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        std::cout << current->data << ' ';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    dll<int> list;

    list.insert( 10 );
    list.insert( 20 );
    list.insert( 15 );

    list.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
10 15 20
```